# Linearization a quadratiqe programming

Tags: quadratic-programming

I have programming problem with multiplication on its variables as $x_i x_j$. I introduced a substitution as $w_{ij}=x_i x_j$. But I cant show the relation between the results of the first and the second problems.

Comment: @dxiv that is true.. I delete my comment then :))

Comment: You made an error on line $13$. Seriously, see [How do I ask a good question?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How did you enforce $w_{i,j}=x_{i}x_{j}$?  Did you keep the original $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$ variables in the problem?